# Python print to terminal shell unicode

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, codec, mojibake

I am parsing a long string of persian in python, and am opening it like this:

```
fp = codecs.open(f+i, 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
```

and using

```
print(line[1])
```

but instead of printing out readable Persian, it outputs things like this in the terminal.

```
Ø§Ø·Ù
     Ø§Ø¹âØ±Ø³Ø§Ù
```

On the webpage, it outputs it fine.

What is the issue with it? Thank you

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: What does `import sys; sys.stdout.encoding` show? Is that correct for your console / terminal?

Comment: @merlin2011 I'm using SSH secure shell

Comment: This looks like a ISO-8851-1 Mojibake of the UTF-8.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've used that before for a previous python script and it worked, so I'm not sure why it's not working for me this time with the same terminal

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, specifically I did import sys and sys.stdout = codecs.getreader('utf-8')(sys.stdout)

Comment: @user3325170: oh, that was perhaps not the best idea? You do get UTF-8 output, but whatever is *reading* those UTF-8 bytes is printing them as Latin 1 instead.

Comment: @user3325170: are you looking at this text on a Windows machine perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes it's on a windows. Ok I will reply more to your comment below!

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39528462/5284370) out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a [CP1252 Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) here. The first character is the code point [U+0627 ARABIC LETTER ALEF](http://codepoints.net/U+0627), encoded to UTF-8, but then *interpreted* as [CP1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252):

```
>>> print u'\u0627'.encode('utf8').decode('cp1252')
Ø§
```

Your SSH shell is misconfigured somewhere; the remote shell thinks you are using UTF-8, while locally the printed UTF-8 bytes are being printed as if they were CP1252 bytes.

What I can decipher is:

- `Ø§` -> [`ا` U+0627 ARABIC LETTER ALEF](http://codepoints.net/U+0627)
- `Ø·` -> [`ط` U+0637 ARABIC LETTER TAH](http://codepoints.net/U+0637)
- `Ø¹` -> [`ع` U+0639 ARABIC LETTER AIN](http://codepoints.net/U+0639)
- `Ø±` -> [`ر` U+0631 ARABIC LETTER REH](http://codepoints.net/U+0631)
- `Ø³` -> [`س` U+0633 ARABIC LETTER SEEN](http://codepoints.net/U+0633)

The `Ù` character is a Mojibake starting point for anything in the U+640 to U+0660 range; we cannot see the second byte for the two occurrences here. Ditto for the `â` character; the second byte wasn't printable in CP1252 so it is again missing.

Overall, what I can recover is:

```
>>> print u'Ø§Ø· - Ø§Ø¹ - Ø±Ø³Ø§'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
اط - اع - رسا
```

Comment: Thank you, I would not have known this if you didn't let me know. I will have to look more into this and get back to you about it. Perhaps tweek some things with my shell...will let you know!

Comment: @user3325170: it is CP1252, the Windows Latin-1 approximate codepage