# Printing Arabic text file in python3

Tags: python, ascii

hello i want to print a Arabic text file in python3, and this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# encoding: utf-8
#Read from the input file
input_file = open('triggertest.txt', 'r+')
for line in input_file:
    print (line)
```

**But i got this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 6, in <module>
    for line in input_file:
  File "/Users/emansaad/anaconda/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

when trying this solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# encoding: utf-8
#Read from the input file
input_file = open('triggertest.txt', 'r+',encoding='utf-8')
for line in input_file:
    print (line)
```

**I got this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 7, in <module>
    print (line)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**triggertest.txt:**

```
مرحبا
مرحباً بك
السلام عليكم
وعليكم السلام
ماهو سعر الايفون٧؟
يأتي بسعتين ٣٢ قيقا ب ٢٤٩٩ ريال  و ١٢٨ قيقا ٢٨٩٩ ريال
```

when run `locale` :

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

when run locale `charmap` :

```
US-ASCII
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 print() function with Farsi/Arabic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528462/python-3-print-function-with-farsi-arabic-characters)

Comment: @cosinepenguin i tired the solutions but no luck

Comment: What is an example of a line in `triggertest.txt`?

Comment: @cosinepenguin i updated the question with the txt file

Comment: Your code is working for me.

Comment: @GergesDib  because it is working for English but when i change the text languge to Arabic i got this error , can it be with the terminal or the python3

Comment: @ImanSaad I used the file sample triggertest.txt you gave... It prints the output correctly in Ipython (pycharm), a little bit garbled in the terminal. I'm using python 3.6.1

Comment: @GergesDib i have python3.5 do i need to update it?

Comment: Not sure... what is `type(line)`?

Comment: @GergesDib do you mean print(line) it just printing to the terminal

Comment: @GergesDib  i saw in another question here that it could be  that my locale and/or environment is broken so when i ran local i got this : LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=

Comment: @Imansaad This might be it. Try using `sys.stdout.buffer.write(line.encode('utf-8'))` instead of `print`

Comment: @GergesDib the same problem :(

Comment: @EmanSaad are you on Windows, OS X, or Linux (e.g. Ubuntu)? It sounds like "The problem is with your terminal that can not output unicode characters."

Comment: @downshift i'm on OS X Serria

Comment: what happens when you do `python3 try.py > test.txt`  and open the file using an editor.

Comment: thank you all i have solved the problem with updating the .bash_profile

Comment: -- cool good job!

Answer (score 0):

use arabic_reshaper

```
import arabic_reshaper

text_to_be_reshaped = 'اللغة العربية رائعة'
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text_to_be_reshaped)
display_text = get_display(reshaped_text) #### important
print(display_text)
```

https://pypi.org/project/arabic-reshaper/

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
text = "مرحبا "

print(text.encode('utf8'))
```

check this tutorial [Arabic in python](https://youtu.be/XAltxpquzsA)

Comment: i got this output : b'\xd9\x85\xd8\xb1\xd8\xad\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7 ' and when i removed the ".encode('utf8')" it goes back to the error in the question

Comment: i saw in another question here that it could be  that my locale and/or environment is broken so when i ran local i got this : LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=