# How to use UTF-8 in python when user input Persian or Arabic

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

My code is about getting names of some users and some points about them and write them into a text file as table. For example:

> 19(someSpace*)|حمید
>
> 20(someSpace*)|وحید
>
> 70(someSpace*)|خلیل
>
> 14(someSpace*)|Hamid

```
def roww(STR, n):
    if n >= 10:
        return str(n) +4*" " +"| " + STR + "\n"
    else:
        return str(n) +5*" " +"|" + STR + "\n"

def my_table(STR, m):
    import sys  
    reload(sys)  
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
    import codecs as D
    f = D.open(STR + '.txt', "w", encoding='utf-8')
    i = 0
    while(i < m):
        i +=1
        a = raw_input("Name: ").encode('utf-8')
        b = raw_input("Grade: ")
        f.write(roww(a,b))
    f.close()
```

when execute:

```
my_table("grade",3)
Name: حمید
```

I get this error:

```
    UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a48ceb393d9a> in <module>()
----> 1 my_table("grade",3)

<ipython-input-9-6a83996822a3> in my_table(STR, m)
     14     while(i < m):
     15         i +=1
---> 16         a = raw_input("Name: ").encode('utf-8')
     17         b = raw_input("Grade")
     18         f.write(roww(a,b))

C:\Users\Hamid\Anaconda2\lib\encodings\utf_8.pyc in decode(input, errors)
     14 
     15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
---> 16     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
     17 
     18 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I can't solve my problem with python about utf-8. Also I can't find any useful answer.

Comment: Have you put the line `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the very top of your file?

Comment: No! How can I do it?

Comment: Check up on this post, it should contain all the information you need: https://sopython.com/canon/88/how-do-i-use-non-ascii-strings-in-my-python-script/

Comment: Putting the encoding at the top of the file will not help you in this particular case. It only determines the encoding of the *source file itself*. Yours is a runtime problem. Due to how Python 2 "works", `raw_input("Name: ").encode('utf-8')` is actually equivalent to `raw_input("Name: ").decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')` and it would seem that your input bytes do not contain UTF-8 encoded text.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä  What should I do?

Comment: This might be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477061/how-to-read-unicode-input-and-compare-unicode-strings-in-python. The trick is to try and determine the encoding used by your terminal, if using your application through such. That boils down to: you should always know your input's encoding.

Comment: I add   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    just before "when execute" but it doesn't help! I get the same error.

Comment: @ Ilja Everilä  the link you gave was useful. But new problem is some symbol "?" instead of some letter in file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example, which demonstrates how you would `read` / `decode` and write an arabic text file. As Ilja already pointed out, it basically depends on your terminal, and as you are getting from the terminal an already `utf-8` encoded bytecode, you actually have to decode it.

> **Works fine on MacOSx:**

If you run this snippet and give as input `المدرالمدرالمدر` it will work fine.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
x = raw_input("test: ").decode("utf-8")
print x
f = open("testarabic.txt", "w")
f.write(x.encode("utf-8"))
f.close()
```

The first line`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`is not needed in your case, unless you have some static text in your python file.

> **Workaround on Windows**

I've just gave it a try on windows and as you said, i am getting as well `?????` characters, but i realized that the windows command line is using a different encoding. So the first question is, if your command line already shows arabic characters correctly, than figure out what `codepage` it is using by typing in terminal

1) Get Code Page of your Terminal

```
chcp
Active code page:1256
```

2) Use the active code you got in your terminal to decode your raw-input

```
x = raw_input("test: ").decode("1256")
```

> If your command line on windows wasn't showing arabic signs correctly you can set it by typing in the windows command line `chcp 1256`

Comment: I ran your code and I got this:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: That's weird, what terminal are you using? Windows? Linux?

Comment: I use Windows 7.1

Comment: Hmm...that might be a Windows thingy...i don't have a windows machine currently to test...maybe in 8 hours.

Comment: This post has some discussion on windwos+Farsi issues, but since the error arise at decoding level, and not during a print statement, I assumed that might not be it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528462/python-3-print-function-with-farsi-arabic-characters

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 1256 doesn't  work for some letters and again I see "?". In my command chcp is 720. I put 720 in my code but it give me error. 
In my command line I can't write Persian and it shows unknown symbols.